# Npm said I don't have yarn, but I already installed with Npm

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am doing my nestjs project.
I recently setup my new macbook pro.

I have Node, Npm, and Yarn installed.
But when I tried to install class-validator and class-transformer package with Npm,
I got a error message :

Unsupported engine. required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }, current: { node: 'v15.11.0', npm: '7.6.0' }

But when I type npm -g ls, or yarn --version, yarn is there.
How should I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node` version seems to be fine because we have in the above case `15.11.0` and the requirement is `>= 10.13.0`, which means that any version higher than `10.13.0` is fine. (Including higher major versions as well.)

The required `npm` version is `^6.11.0` and the current version is `7.6.0`. The `^` character in the requirement means, that the major version should be identical and the minor and patch version can change to a higher version. (Versioning terms are [documented here](https://semver.org/).)

This means, that the installed `npm` version should have major version `6`, in the above case we have `7`. It follows that an `npm` version should be used that has `6` as major version.

Comment: Then I should just delete NPM and reinstall version 6. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I suggest trying that.